# I don't know how to delete a list created from an observable

Tags: angular

I was trying to delete something from a project I'm working on, and I don't know how to do a put server request.
The put request works properly, but the view is not updated after receiving the response.

```
 markNotificationsAsReaded(not): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.put(`${environment.url}/notifications/view`, { "notification_id": not.id }).pipe(map(res => { return res })).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          resolve(res);
          console.log('marcando como leido esto 2', res)
        },
        error => {
          reject();
        });
    })
  }
```

and this is the HTML code

```
<app-notification
            *ngFor="let n of notificationService.notificationsList$ | async; let idx=index" 
            [idx]="idx"
            [notification]="n"[]
            (removeNotification)="getNotification(idx)" 
        >
        <h4 ></h4>
        </app-notification>
```

I'm new in this, sorry if it is a basic error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to update the variable 'notificationService.notificationsList$. By default http request is made only once.

So even with the asynchronous pipe you will have to call the function that creates this list again.